# Ways to include custom error messages in shorthand if-else sanity checks Discord JS

Tags: node.js, if-statement, discord.js

I am a beginner and probably, this is a stupid question. I am writing a command handler for a discord.js bot. Every time, a user sends a message starting with the correct command prefix, I check whether the invoke is in an Enmap of possible commands.
Currently, it looks like this:

```
const command = client.commands.get(invoke);
if(!command) return;
...
```

I would like to keep this shorthand way of writing those sanity checks, but I would like to inform the user that there is no command with this name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend telling the user if a command is invalid, but here's how you can do it:

```js
const command = client.commands.get(command);
if (!command) return message.channel.send("Invalid Command.");
```